# Assigning Values to Variables inside of an Array

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to coding and can't find out why this is outputting undefined:

```
var var0, list = [var0];
list[0] = true;
console.log(var0)
```

Comment: You never assign anything to `var0`. What do you expect it to be?

Comment: I'm assigning true to list[0] which from what I understand should be var0

Comment: No, `list[0]` is the first item of the list. You don't have pointers and references here, just values - `[var0]` just creates an array `[undefined]`, nothing more. There is no relation with the variable after the creation of `list`.

Comment: `list[0]` contains a copy of the value of `var0` variable. Assigning `true` to `list[0]` doesn't assigns the value to `var0` as well. `list[0] = true` will just overwrite the value at index 0 in `list`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: @VLAZ No, I couldn't find what I was looking for there

Comment: @HarryLandesburg why? It very clearly explains that it's not a pass-by-reference language, hence you cannot expect changing a variable to change a copy of it or vice versa. I'm not sure what other explanation you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

On line 1 you copy the **value** of `var0` into the array.

On line 2 you replace the **value** in the array.

This doesn't have any effect on `var0`. That is just a variable that used to have a *copy* of the same *value*. It is not a reference.

Comment: That makes sense, but how then can I store var0 inside that array so that it's value can be modified?

Comment: You can't. JavaScript doesn't have explicit references.

Comment: @HarryLandesburg it's impossible. If you share [what your overall goal is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), we can probably advise how to approach it. Right now, it sounds like you probably just want to store your values in an object.

Comment: Darn, I'd expect that to be possible :/

Comment: @VLAZ I was attempting to check which arrow key is pressed making the code shorter than with if statements:
`window.addEventListener('keydown', KD);
var left, up, right, down, list = [left, up, right, down];
function KD(event) {
    let LA = 0;
    for (a = 37; a !== 41; a++) {
        if (event.keyCode == a) {
            list[LA] = true;
        }
        LA++
    }
    LA = 0;
}`
I guess I'll have to go back to using a bunch of if statements...

Comment: @HarryLandesburg ...or use an object as I already said.

Comment: @VLAZ Objects can store variables then? I'm confused

Comment: @HarryLandesburg not "store variables" but you can just use one as a central location to store related values. If you change `keys.left = true` in one place, it'd be visible everywhere. If you make another object with a mapping between key code and your name for the keys, you don't need many `if`s just `key[mapping[event.keyCode]] = true` You can throw an `if` for when something doesn't exist in `mapping`, perhaps but otherwise you don't have much code to note down what was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You never use or define the value of var0.

```
list[0] = true;
```

This line replaces the value of the object in the 0 position (which is var0 because of the first line) to a boolean variable with the value "true".

What you mean to do is

```
var var0 = true, list = [var0];
console.log(list[0])
```

Comment: I know I could assign it true already but I'm trying to store it inside an array then set the first variable to true

Comment: @HarryLandesburg - you can't because that's not how javascript works.
You never pass a variable, just the value of the variable.